# Google Sheets - Waterfall Chart Subtotal Labels

Tags: google-sheets

[Here's a data sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CuuwPMB9svlwz8YpoXYFSYpD7yXg9xsGQO9xGH-_M8M/edit?usp=sharing)
[and screenshots too](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NsgxY.jpg).
I'm trying to make a waterfall chart with Start/End year performance and contributions. I was trying to make the chart more descriptive by including a customized label, with percentage variations.

No matter how I select the labels column, the ending Subtotal bar is independent from the others. I'm trying to customize both bottom and top labels, but I'm more concerned on the top one (the growth/loss percentage or the absolute value at the end of the year.

Comment: From the Spreadsheet example, I see the subtotal column with an expected value. Is it correct now?

Comment: The Subtotal column magnitude is correct, but I'm not able to put on it a label like with the other columns.

I edited the sheet and added more charts to explain better. Ideally I would like to have the first case, but with a value on the Subtotal column as well (Like in the second case). As simple as it sounds I'm quite stuck.

Should also be noted that the first two charts apply labels from a different source in the editor, and none use the cell value of "Last Year" in the sheet itself

Comment: I may be misunderstanding the issue, but if you add a minus sign to your SUM formula in N11 (for end of year) and a minus sign in O11, so that the label is made positive, doesn't that correctly label your chart, in Test4?   That gives % labels for the middle columns, and an integer label for the last column.   Or does the last column on the chart need to be grey, like the start of year column?

Comment: Thanks @kirkg13! with your hint I was able to make a solution that is 100% in line with that I needed. In the end I just needed to remove the "default" subtotal, and add a "custom subtotal" in place of the column "Last Year". No need for negative.

Comment: Glad you've got it worked out.  I'll look at your sample sheet to see what you've down with the custom sub-total...

Comment: Hello @ABO, sorry for the late reply. Could you post the solution you found as an answer? Thanks :)

Comment: Hi @Jescanellas, I just uploaded the answer. Hope it's clear enough and will help someone in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Thanks again to @kirkg13 for guiding me through the solution. It was not quite difficult in the end, but I think the option should be made clearer/simpler in some future updates.

You can check my solution on the Chart 4 from the [sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CuuwPMB9svlwz8YpoXYFSYpD7yXg9xsGQO9xGH-_M8M/) file as long as It'll be online. Steps are as follows:

1: Lay the data in three columns: Column names, values (start value, absolute deltas and end values) and custom labels (whatever you like, in my case % variations for all columns except start/end). Include the subtotal column

[image: Step 1]

2: On the chart editor make sure all the data is selected, including the sub-total (from Start Year to End Year in my example). Check that x-axis and series are correctly assigned (column 1 and 2); from the series click and add a label, selecting the third column.

[image: Step 2]

3: This is the part I had difficulties finding: on customize>series>data labels, you need to:

- Uncheck the "Add subtotal..." box (optionally check the "Use first value as subtotal" one, for better color clarity
- Below, click "Add new subtotal".
- The new Subtotal must be of "type" "Replacing" and "column index" as the last column you have

[image: Step 3]

The end result is as below: all columns have a customizable name and label, with coherent colors.

[image: Final]

Comment: Well explained answer!